# Proving the Computability of the Function $\beta$ Analogous to Another Function

Tags: computability

I am studying a Theory of Computability.

Before the theorem I should provide you with the definition of limited sum and product, respectfully:

$\alpha(x,y)=\sum_{z<y}f(x,z)$ which is defined with relations:

$\alpha(x,0)=0$ and $\alpha(x,y+1)=\alpha(x,y)+f(x,y)$

and now product:

$\beta(x,y)=\sqcap_{z<y}f(x,z)$ which is defined with relations:

$\beta(x,0)=1$ and $\beta(x,y+1)=\beta(x,y)*f(x,y)$

Given the following theorem:

Theorem: Let $f(x,y)$ be a total computable function. Then the functions
$\alpha(x,y)$ and $\beta(x,y)$ are also computable.

Proof for $\alpha$:

We note that the functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are obtained through primitive recursion from computable functions, hence they are computable.

We have:
$\alpha(x,0)=0=0(x)$

$0(x)$ is a computable function.

Further:
$\alpha(x,y+1)=\alpha(x,y)+f(x,y)=g(x,y,\alpha(x,y))$
where:

$g(x,y,z)=z+f(x,y)=\cup_{n+2}^{n+2} (x,y,z)+f(x,y)$
is computable as a sum of computable functions.

Now, I want to prove the computability of $\beta$ analogously to $\alpha$. My question is if this approach is good and is there anything that is incorrect or missing?

$\beta(x,0)=1$, which is a computable function since it is constant.

Further:
$\beta(x,y+1)=\beta(x,y)*f(x,y)=g(x,y,\beta(x,y))$
where:

$g(x,y,z)=z*f(x,y)=?$
I am kinda stuck here...

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean with $\cup_{n+2}^{n+2} ...$, but if you are using the fact that the sum of computable functions is computable you might as well use the fact that the product of computable functions is computable. So the function mapping $x,y,z$ to $z*f(x,y)$ is computable.